# How to verify a unidirectional TVS diode

Tags: diodes, tvs

For a unidirectional TVS diode, can I verify its operation by simply raising a DC voltage on it?
Should I be able to reasonably obtain the expected results as shown in the curve below, where I can increase a positive DC voltage across it and then see it draw more current?

The specifications of various TVS diodes show that they use an 8/20 us current waveform, implying that there should be a dynamic response as opposed to a static one, but I am not sure.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to verify its operation in circuit or as a bare part?

Comment: Yes you could.   You will also want to put a resistor in series because soon as it starts conducting, if there's no resistor it'll take as much current as your supply will provide and then POOF.    The 8-20uS thing is probably to show you how fast they respond.   That will be a little trickier to test for as now you'd need an oscilloscope....

Comment: @vir As a bare part. As per some suggestions, I'll add a resistor into the circuit as well. And yes, I have an oscilloscope to verify things as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use a short pulse in the testing because if you use a long pulse at  high current the power dissipation will change the characteristics, permanently if left long enough.

You can verify the initial part of clamping but putting a resistor in series with the part and raising the voltage until you see the 'knee', but limit the dissipation to something reasonable for the ratings. To do testing at high current you'd need to use a more sophisticated arrangement (which could be DIY) but short sharp pulses at very high currents can be tricky since even a bit of inductance changes the behavior.

You may be able to use the current limit in a bench power supply for static testing, but some care is called for since the limiting is not intended for this purpose- for example if the connection is  broken and re-established there may be a large current pulse due to capacitance of the power supply. So I suggest using a resistor.